# highcharts solid gauge with multiple data label values

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a highcharts solid gauge within which I want to display some additional data in the form of text labels. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/ogkad0fy/#&togetherjs=PkPTqTbm45.

The gauge itself and the main data label are updated with the following function:

```
function updatetemp() {
    var point;
    point = chartTemperature.series[0].points[0];
    point.update(gauge_temp_outdoor);
}
```

and the additional data labels using jquery:

```
$("#temp_max_day").html(data2.th0.temp_max_today);
$("#temp_min_day").html(data2.th0.temp_min_today);
```

The update function and the jquery updates don't occur at the same time and this seems to result in some erratic behaviour such as the additional labels disappearing or changing position when the update function is called and then reappearing and changing position again when the jquery update of the element id occurs.

Is there a better way of doing this so that the two asynchronously occurring updates don't conflict with each other?

Thanks,

Baobab

EDIT: additional data labels are currently updated by the following function. This function is triggered by a certain incoming MQTT message. This works well except for the described issue.

```
function onMessageArrived(message) {
   console.log("onMessageArrived: " + message.payloadString);
   if (message.destinationName == "myHome/mb/json_string") {
        var data2 = JSON.parse(message.payloadString);
        $("#temp_max_month").html(data2.th0.temp_max_thismonth);
        $("#temp_min_month").html(data2.th0.temp_min_thismonth);
        $("#temp_max_day").html(data2.th0.temp_max_today);
        $("#temp_min_day").html(data2.th0.temp_min_today);
        $("#temp_max_year").html(data2.th0.temp_max_thisyear);
   }
```

Comment: I cannot see those additional update function in the demo which you have shared. Have you considered using the SVGRenderer tool to render those custom text? https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer

Comment: I've added the second function used to update the additional data labels to my post. I have considered using the SVGRenderer tool but have not found a way to update what it renders dynamically without reloading the entire gauge - https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=36507.

Comment: Could you reproduce your attempt of using the SVGRenderer on some online editor? I am not sure what kind of reloading you have in mind.